# Is the sample variance $S_{n}^2 \xrightarrow{ L^2} \sigma^2$?

Tags: statistics, asymptotics, variance

I am not sure my attempt is correct. I have seen proofs for the convergence of sample variance in probability. I wonder if showing $L^2$ convergence (in quadratic mean) could be an easier way of showing convergence in probability.

Let ${X_i}$ be iid with $\mu = \mathbb{E}(X_1)$ and $\sigma^2 = \mathbb{V}(X_1)$

$S_{n}^2 = \frac{1}{n-1} \sum (X_i - \bar{X_n})$

My attempt:

$\mathbb{E}[(S_{n}^2 - \sigma^2 )^2] = \mathbb{E} [(S_{n}^2)^2 - 2S_{n}^2\sigma^2 + (\sigma^2)^2 ]   \\= \mathbb{E}[S_{n}^2] -2\sigma^2\mathbb{E}[S_{n}^2]+ (\sigma^2)^2    \\=  \mathbb{V}[S_{n}^2] + \mathbb{E}[S_{n}^2]^2-(\sigma^2)^2      \\= \sigma^2/n$

This tends to zero as n tends to infinity and with markov inequality we show convergence in probability, or rather $L^2$ implies convergence in probability.

My only concern could be that I am misunderstanding something because I could find a similar statement anywhere and my textbook (All of Statistics, Wasserman) gives a hint that isn't similar.

Comment: I'm not sure how you get to the last line from the second to last. In particular, $Var(S_n^2)$ depends on the fourth moment.

Comment: (And it would be proportional to $\sigma^4$)

Comment: @spaceisdarkgreen My mistake is treating the sample variance as $X^2$  and $E[X^2] = V(X^2) + E[X]^2$.   Should be $E[(S_{n}^2)^2]$

Comment: Yes, it's more complicated.. there's cross terms in the sum. The answer's here https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variance#Distribution_of_the_sample_variance. Note you're only going to be able to to do the finite fourth moment case this way (no $L^2$ convergence otherwise). You can use the strong law and convergence a.s. for the general case though.

Comment: @spaceisdarkgreen Alright, thanks. I see my error very clearly.$V(S^2) \neq \sigma^2 /n$. That's a flub confusing sample variance with sample mean.